# Ruby to Reverse words of a single string separated by an underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string "XMR_DASH". Using Ruby I want it to read "DASH_XMR". So essentially I need to flip the string horizontally between the underscore without reversing the letters. Can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"XMR_DASH".split("_").reverse.join("_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
[2] pry(main)> 'DASH_XMR'.split('_').reverse.join('_')
"XMR_DASH"
```

Methods used: [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split), [Array#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-reverse), [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-join)